# Problema de identacion - python

Tags: mysql, python

Disculpen por la consulta media tonta. ¿Cómo soluciono el problema de indentación en la linea 54? Se que es un problema de espaciado, pero no logro sacar ese error.
https://pastebin.com/kYt572fJ

```
import os
from threading import Timer
from os.path import isfile, join, exists
import shutil
import MySQLdb
import time
import datetime
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\Users\BetaBrawler\Downloads\Informe\Informe.txt', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

PATH_TO_WATCH = "C:\Users\BetaBrawler\Downloads"

class FileReader:

    def __init__(self, path = None):
        self.path = path
        self.running = False
        self.timer = None

    def printFilesData(self, files):
        if self.path:
            timestamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
            destination = join(self.path, timestamp)
            for index, file in enumerate(files):
             if isfile(join(self.path, file)):
              try:
               conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="watcherservice")
               cur = conn.concusor()
               cur.execute("INSERT INTO detalles (timestamp) VALUES (?)", (timestamp))

    def readAndMoveFile(self, fileData):

        logging.debug("Archivo:%s%s" % (fileData["name"], fileData["data"].read()))

        #El archivo debe ser cerrado para que se mueve
        fileData["data"].close()

        if not exists(fileData["dest"]):
            os.makedirs(fileData["dest"])
        try:
            shutil.move(join(self.path, fileData["name"]), fileData["dest"])
            logging.debug("Archivo \"%s\" movido  \"%s\" ." % (fileData["name"], fileData["dest"]))
        except WindowsError as e:
            logging.warning(e)

    def listFiles(self):
        if self.path:
            return [file for file in os.listdir(self.path)]
        return None

    def stopWatching(self):
        logging.warning("Not watching.")
        self.timer.cancel()

    def complete(self):
        after = self.listFiles()
        added = [file for file in after if not file in self.lock]
        self.printFilesData(added)
        self.lock = after
        self.timer = Timer(5.0, self.complete)
        self.timer.start()

    def startWatching(self):
        if(self.path):
            self.lock = self.listFiles()
            logging.debug("Directorio que se esta observando %s..." % self.path)
            self.printFilesData(self.lock)
            self.timer = Timer(5.0, self.complete)
            self.timer.start()
        else: logging.warning("Ruta sin definir.")

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.reader = FileReader("C:\Users\BetaBrawler\Downloads")
        self.reader.startWatching()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Main()

    #Debug: Seguimiento mas acusioso
    #Info: Informacion
    #Warning
    #Critical
```

Comment: Copie el codigo a su pregunta

Comment: Como comenta eyllanesc debes agregar el código a la pregunta, un enlace externo dificulta la lectura, no se indexará en las búsquedas el contenido y puede dejar de estar disponible por lo que la pregunta dejaría de tener sentido. Para formatear el código simplemente lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k`. El error es muy simple, te falta algo en la función anterior.... ese `try` está muy solo.

Comment: Cierto, ya puse el codigo como corresponde. Lamento haberme olvidado de ese detalle.

Comment: No crees que debiera ir un `except` después del `try`?

Answer (score 1):

Si mira desde la linea 46 esta mal "indentado":

```
def printFilesData(self, files):
    if self.path:
        timestamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
        destination = join(self.path, timestamp)
        for index, file in enumerate(files):
            if isfile(join(self.path, file)):
                try:
                    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="watcherservice")
                    cur = conn.concusor()
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO detalles (timestamp) VALUES (?)", (timestamp))
```

[image]